# Do "hiding behind"/"when hide behind" convey the same meaning here?

Tags: difference

1. > Guitarists find security hiding behind the bulky instrument.
2. > Guitarists find security when hide behind the bulky instrument.

Are these sentences the same?

Comment: No, they are not. The first is puzzling and poorly constructed because no instrument has been specified and, if guitars are implied, they are not particularly bulky. The second is wrong. It would be correct - but with the same faults - if you inserted the word **they** before **hide**.

Comment: Whoever wrote this has never seen a guitar. Guitars are not bulky! Also, neither sentence is capitalized correctly. The last sentence is grammatically incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The second sentence has an error.  The word "hide" should be "hiding".

Beyond that, the two sentences are slightly different. The first sentence says that hiding behind the bulky instrument is what provides the security. The second sentence allows a possibility that the security is merely coincidental with hiding behind the bulky instrument. Compare with:

Consider for comparison:

"The president gets fish visiting Boston." This sounds strange. A president doesn't visit Boston for the purpose of getting fish. Also, visiting Boston doesn't automatically cause the president to have fish. A better sentence might be, "The president gets votes visiting Boston."

"The president gets fish when visiting Boston." This sounds normal. The president makes a habit of going to his favorite seafood to get his favorite food whenever he visits Boston.  The restaurant isn't his reason for going to Boston. Not is it normal that everyone who visits Boston gets fish.

Comment: The second one is just wrong.  "when hide behind"?

Comment: @stangdon  Thanks, I missed that.  So edited.